# Can i use bridge interface for host connection by virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

On Virtual box,
I have a simply question. I want network connectivity between my virtual box and local host. Can I achieve this using bridge-interface?

My setup:

- Windows 7
- Latest Virtual Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  With bridged the virtual host will have it's own local network ip address.  If using dhcp it will pull an IP from your dhcp server just like your window machine does.

It will look/function like any normal host on your network.   Your windows box can hit the virtual machines IP and the virtual machine will be able to hit your windows system.